# R - longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

Tags: r

I am doing this:

```
RMSE <- (sum((RFestimated-model1$y)^2)/length(model1$y))^(1/2)
```

where:
mode1 is regression model from a Random Forest and y is the value being predicted from the Training data
RFestimated is the predicted value from the test data

I am trying to calculate RMSE
Is there a trick to making the lengths equal?

These are my steps: (code)

```
# sample 80% of the data for training -random sample
train_index <- sample(1:nrow(beijingData), 0.8 * nrow(beijingData))
# take the difference as data to test the model
test_index <- setdiff(1:nrow(beijingData), train_index)

#create Train and Test data sets based on the indexes above.
dataTrain <-  beijingData[train_index,]
dataTest <- beijingData[test_index,]

#check the datasets dimensions
dim(dataTrain)
dim(dataTest)

> dim(dataTrain)
[1] 33405    13
> dim(dataTest)
[1] 8352   13

#set seed
set.seed(100)
#create a random forest regression model
model1 <- randomForest(pm2.5 ~ ., data = dataTrain, ntree=500, importance = 
TRUE)
model1

#predict with test data
RFestimated <- predict(model1, dataTest)

[1] 118.7794
> length(RFestimated)
[1] 8352
> length(model1$y)
[1] 33405

qqnorm((RFestimated - model1$y)/sd(RFestimated-model1$y))

qqline((RFestimated-model1$y)/sd(RFestimated-model1$y))

#results of last tow statements above
> qqnorm((RFestimated - model1$y)/sd(RFestimated-model1$y))
Warning messages:
1: In RFestimated - model1$y :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
2: In RFestimated - model1$y :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
> 
> qqline((RFestimated-model1$y)/sd(RFestimated-model1$y))
Warning messages:
1: In RFestimated - model1$y :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
2: In RFestimated - model1$y :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

Comment: Please see [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). You will likely get an answer to your question more quickly if you have a reproducible example. Provide the smallest input data needed to reproduce what you are asking and the desired output.

Comment: I have a hunch that `model1$y` is the original `y` and has a different length than your predicted values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at these lines here:

```
#predict with test data
RFestimated <- predict(model1, dataTest)

[1] 118.7794
> length(RFestimated)
[1] 8352
> length(model1$y)
[1] 33405
```

What you see is that their lengths differ. How is this supposed to work? Think about what you are trying to do:

```
a <- c(1,2,3)
b <- c(4,5)
a-b
[1] -3 -3 -1
Warning message:
In a - b : longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

You either need to evaluate the RMSE on the train data, or on the test data, but you are mixing them. That is, either this

```
RFestimated <- predict(model1, dataTrain)
qqnorm((RFestimated - model1$y)/sd(RFestimated-model1$y))
```

would work, or this:

```
RFestimated <- predict(model1, dataTest)
qqnorm((RFestimated - dataTest$y)/sd(RFestimated-dataTest$y))
```

The first option tells you how good you are fitting the data in the sample used for fitting, and the second gives you the performance on the test data.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my mistake. I see now that I was not comparing like with like